# Can we use neo4j and mongodb same time?

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am new to neo4j and the current project I'm working on uses MongoDB as database, I have a new requirement to show recommendations and visualize data using neo4j. I have no option to replace MongoDB with neo4j and if I am using both DBs I will have to dump data to neo4j every time to get updated data from MongoDB. Is there any better solution for this?

Comment: Please clarify your question. So you are required to "visualize data using neo4j" but you don't want to update data in neo4j? Neo4j is a database and not a visualization tool.  Please give us examples, data, diagrams so that we understand the question. thanks.

Comment: You've got a plenty of visualization libraries, I'd use something like this rather than additional database only used for the visualization purpose
https://www.monterail.com/blog/javascript-libraries-data-visualization

Comment: Do you mean “calculate” recommendations instead of just visualizing them ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MongoDB as caching and put all your data in Neo4j, but not a good idea to use Neo4j just for data visualization